# Handlebar JS outputting duplicate database information. How do I fix this?

Tags: duplicates, handlebars.js

I am working with a catalog program called eLumen (database for community college). They utilize Handlebar JS, and I am a novice. I got my code to work to pull in the correct data; however, on some pages the code is applied it is duplicating information and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
{{#if object.genEdList}}
        <ul>
          {{#each object.genEdList as |gel|}}
            
              {{#each gel.categoryList as |gcl|}}
                    {{#equals gcl.status 'Approved'}}
                        <li>{{gel.name}}: 
                    {{/equals}}
                {{/each}}
                
                {{#each gel.categoryList as |gcl|}}
                    {{#equals gcl.status 'Approved'}}
                        ({{gcl.name}}) 
                    {{/equals}}
                {{/each}}
                
                {{#each gel.comparableCourses as |gcc|}}
                    {{#equals gcl.status 'Approved'}}
                        ({{gcc.name}})
                    {{/equals}}
                {{/each}}
                
                {{#each gel.categoryList as |gcl|}}
                    {{#equals gel.name 'C-ID'}} 
                        ({{comparableCourses}})
                    {{/equals}}
              {{/each}} 
            </li> 
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      {{else}} Not approved for General Education
{{/if}}
```

It should be pulling information from the database and looking for 'Approved' status to pull in the gel.name and the other components. This works, but on same pages it is duplicating the gel.name and leaving the other information blank.

Any ideas would be great! If you need more details, let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should give an example of the data you are passing to this template. Also, I think it is worth noting that the placement of the opening and closing `li` tags look suspicious - the opener is within an `#each` and an `#equals` that the closer isn't.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am completely new to this so there are bound to be errors. Thank you for taking note! Any suggestions on that? The data that is being passed is listed under "Transfer and General Education" on this page: https://bakersfield.elumenapp.com/catalog/2023-2024/course/admjb40

Comment: Could you include the data (or a relevant sample of it) in the post?

Comment: I don't have access to the backend, only the data points that are able to be pulled over. That is why I shared the link in which you can see data being listed/duplicated. I apologize if I'm not understanding your request. I appreciate the support.

Comment: Perhaps you could add `{{log this}}` as the first line in your template and share what gets logged (removing any sensitive data, of course).

Comment: Where should I see that log data? I put in `{{log this}}` but didn't see any information anywhere. Again, I apologize for not just knowing how to help you help me haha.

Comment: That would depend on whether you are rendering this template in the browser or on the server.

Comment: It is rendered in the browser.

Comment: Then you should be able to find the log in the browser's developer console.

Comment: ugh, I don't know how this is being rendered. Nothing is being logged in the developer console through Chrome. I truly appreciate your help, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: I was able to get the duplication to go away by removing the first `#each` statement; however, I am having `gel.name` show up even though it has no other data. This makes sense to be because the code is pulling all instances of `gel.name`, but I'd like it to look for those that are Denied.

Comment: I have had to make some assumptions about what the data looks like. I don't know what `({{comparableCourses}})` is supposed to render. My best guess is that your template should look something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/85o3uzky/

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time in helping me, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Did my fiddle help you?